# SOM for Detection

Tags: matlab, detection, som

I would like to know how I can use SOM for disease detection. Given a lung cancer dataset, how can SOM be applied for detection, there are certain terminologies like, sensitivity, specificity and accuracy percentages....are there ways to calculate all these with the SOM algorithm? I would appreciate answers from anyone who can shed more light on this

Comment: I've voted to close this on the grounds that it is off-topic.  This is not a programming question.

Comment: I'd advice you to join BioStar community at http://biostar.stackexchange.com and ask such questions there.

Answer (score 0):

this might be one example for what you are looking for...

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233734297_A_MATLAB_toolbox_for_Self_Organizing_Maps_and_supervised_neural_network_learning_strategies